# Do the Dickey-Fuller tests assess seasonality as they test the existence of the unit root?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, stationarity, seasonality

It is known that the "Dickey-Fuller tests" test if the times series is stationary or not by testing the existence of the unit root, after fitting the time series to AR(1) process.

Do "Dickey-Fuller tests" give a statistical significance while testing a seasonal time series, knowing that a seasonal time series is non-stationary and needs seasonal differencing?

In another word, can I rely on "Dickey-Fuller tests" in judging that the series needs a seasonal differencing knowing that it has no trend (the reason of non-stationary is only due to seasonality)?

Answer (score 1):

The DF/ADF is testing for the first difference (aka the trend) only. It could iteratively cover larger differences (aka the seasonalities) as well but it is defined as it is. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1opjnegd_hA explains the equations where you will see the value of delta.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't duplicate your posts.  Decide which thread this one belongs in and post it *only* there.  If a post answers two different questions, then evidently those questions are duplicates, so please flag them as such.